# how to get the actual username to display instead of #<User:0x5424a68> (ruby on rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view, I'm using this to display the user

`Made a comment on <%= link_to activity.trackable.micropost.user, activity.trackable.micropost.user %>`

When I do this, it works, but the link shows up as something like `#<User:0x5424a68>`

I tried using `activity.trackable.micropost.user.username`, `activity.trackable.micropost.user.name`, and other variations but they didn't work.

What do I need to add after .user?

The `activity.trackable` is from the PublicActivity gem.

Comment: Who is the creator of the User class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= activity.trackable.micropost.user.inspect %>
```

or

```
  <%= activity.trackable.micropost.user.to_s %>
```

This should give you a decent idea of what you need to add..

Answer (score 2):

Open `rails console` and type:

```
User.instance_methods.grep(/name/)
```

It will give you a list of methods on `User` that contain the string `'name'`. Chances are, that you will find the method you are looking for in the list (if there is any).