# suddenly started getting NoMethodError in Static_pages#home - undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

This is a follow up from this question that I posted yesterday
[how to get the actual username to display instead of #<User:0x5424a68> (ruby on rails 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296402/how-to-get-the-actual-username-to-display-instead-of-user0x5424a68-ruby-on)

I was able to get everything working fine by using `<%= link_to item.trackable.micropost.user.name, item.trackable.micropost.user %>` in `_item.html.erb` view but I'm suddenly getting `undefined method for 'micropost'`. Anyone know why this happened?

It was working fine this morning but here's the full error

```
 NoMethodError in Static_pages#home   
 undefined method `micropost' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's how I'm rendering the partial

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/item', collection: @items %>
```

What would cause the micropost variable to suddenly go undefined when it was working fine before?

Comment: What changes have you made to your models/database.

Comment: I haven't changed much. That's why I'm at a loss. One of the things I added was an array pagination. I added this `@items = @items.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 20)` to the final line inside Static_pages#home. I was able to get `<%= will_paginate @items %>` working for the array. I didn't make any changes to the database.

Comment: I also added `has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy` and `after_save :extract_tags` to the micropost model

Comment: Does your item actually have any microposts attached to it? If it doesn't that can explain why you received that error.

Comment: When I run `inspect`, this is a sample from the gem that it pulled: `#<PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity id: 18, trackable_id: 276, trackable_type: "Micropost", owner_id: 31, owner_type: "User", key: "micropost.create", parameters: {}, recipient_id: nil, recipient_type: nil, created_at: "2013-04-30 22:53:05", updated_at: "2013-04-30 22:53:05"> `. The problem is that the line `item.trackable.micropost.user` was working just fine today but it suddenly became unavailable